Are There Only a Finite Number of Non-Adjacent Integer Pairs with Equal Exponential Powers?
$$
\text{Finding all pairs } (a, b) \text{ such that } a^b = (b-1)^{a+1} \text{ and } |a - b| > 1.
$$
$$
\text{I could only find } (a =8, b=3) \
$$
Are there any more? Are solutions related to prime numbers? Must a or b, be prime?
How would this best be solved to determine a and b values? computations?

Take $a=2$, $b=9$

Welcome to Math SE. Note this is a cross-post of your MathOverflow $a^b=(b-1)^{a+1}$. How many pairs of solutions are there when $|a-b|>1$? from only about an hour ago. Cross-posting is generally frowned on when it's done so relatively quickly, with several meta posts I've seen recommending waiting at least a week before doing so. Regardless, please at least provide links from each post to the other, to help avoid duplication of efforts.

I will consider the case where $a > 0$ and $b > 1$. You can rewrite your equality as $f(a) = f(b-1)$ where $f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{x+1}}$. The derivative of $f$ is given by:
$$f'(x) = x^{\frac{1}{x+1}} \frac{(x+1) - x\log x}{x(x+1)^2}$$
The unique solution to $x + 1 = x\log x$ is $x = 3.591...$, so the function $f$ is increasing till $3.591...$ and decreasing afterwards. On positive integers, we see that $1 = f(2) < f(3) < f(4) > f(5) > \cdots > 1$. Moreover, we also have $f(3) > f(5)$. Thus, the only non-trivial solution we can have to $f(a) = f(b-1)$ in our case is when $a = 2$ or $b - 1 = 2$. Furthermore, each of these cases has at most one solution. Indeed, these precisely correspond to $(a, b) = (2, 9)$ and $(a, b) = (8, 3)$. I leave it as an exercise to you to deal with the general case!
